# Is there a way to distinguish the output from a remote command from the output of ssh itself?

Tags: linux, ssh

I execute a remote command thru ssh and I need to parse the output of that command. The remote stdout/stderr are forwarded fine by ssh back to my local box on the stdout/stderr of my local ssh command. However, this fails when ssh multiplexes its own status/error messages on my local stdout/stderr.

Is there a way to tell my local ssh command to send its own messages to a local file ? Or do I need to make my remote commands send their own outputs to a pair of remote files and then scp them back to parse them safely ?

Comment: `ssh` has a `-q` option to suppress warning and diagnostic messages - is that any help?

Comment: No, it does not remove all messages. i.e., I am trying to write a parser that works all the time and that does not fail when I most need it (that is, when the ssh command is somewhat screwed)

Answer (score 1):

The SSH client has two switches to reduce/eliminate verbosity.

From [man ssh](http://ss64.com/bash/ssh.html):

```
-q       Quiet mode.  Causes all warning and diagnostic messages to be
         suppressed.

-y       Send log information using the syslog(3) system module.  By
         default this information is sent to stderr.
```

The `-y` switch is probably what you want, but it isn't available in all versions.

Ubuntu's current version (OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012) supports it, but others may not.

You can save the logs regarding ssh in a different log file if you wish.

If you're using rsyslog, e.g., create the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/ssh.log` and save the following line to it:

```
:msg,contains,"ssh:" /var/log/ssh.log
```

Now restart rsyslog by executing the following command:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

To access the logs regarding a specific ssh process with PID `$PID`, you can use grep:

```
grep "ssh\[$PID\]" /var/log/ssh.log
```

Comment: Is there a way to intercept the syslog traffic for a specific pid ? i.e., I also want to parse the ssh eror messages...

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am sorry to be annoying but that is going to require that the log files are actually readable by the user that runs the ssh command which is unlikely to happen in practice (too much sensitive data would thus be available). I wonder if it is somewhat possible to run the ssh process with an LD_PRELOAD trick to intercept the udp packets that go to syslog before they get there.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't know enough about that matter to help you. I guess you could either grant the users read privileges to `ssh.log` alone (the most sensitive information should be host names, and you could delete it every couple of minutes) or set up a background job as root that keeps track of the used PIDs and copies the information, based on the PID, in a file readable by that user only.